# Calling viewDidLayoutSubviews from another controller

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want call viewDidLayoutSubviews from TableViewController, which inherits from AnotherViewController.

I tried doing this: `[self.anotherView setNeedsLayout];`

But that doesn't work.

Comment: You can call it directly in your view controller: `[self viewDidLayoutSubviews];`

Comment: Do you mean AnotherViewController?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is intended to only be overridden, not called directly by your own code. It should be harmless to call it yourself, but it's not good practice.

Comment: @Gavin I know this is old, but what is the correct practice for triggering `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?  Can I just use `self.view.setNeedsLayout()`? Is there any correct way of doing it?